# Problems with invalid SessionIndex in Sign Out with SAML2 LogoutRequest

Tags: java, azure, office365, saml, saml-2.0

I am a developer trying to integrate my IdP with Office 365 using SAML 2.

I have had success in the first steps for Logon user. However, I have a lot of doubts about Sign Out (`LogoutRequest`) with IdP-Initiated flow, the doubts are related to endpoints for Sign Out. For developing the Logon, I followed the endpoints and configurations present in this metadata file:

https://nexus.microsoftonline-p.com/federationmetadata/saml20/federationmetadata.xml

Ti send a LogoutRequest, the metadata gives the same url as login:

```
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf"/>
```

I create the LogoutRequest as follows:

```
<saml2p:LogoutRequest Destination="https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf"
                      ID="_263311dc-ce0a-21c3-90d3-2e1312cde124"
                      IssueInstant="2015-01-13T13:51:57.978Z"
                      Version="2.0"
                      xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">

    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://my-enterprise-configuration-value</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
                  SPNameQualifier="https://my-enterprise-configuration-value"
                  xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">my-configuration-name-id-in-o365</saml2:NameID>
    <samlp:SessionIndex>_session-index-generate-in-saml-response</samlp:SessionIndex>
</saml2p:LogoutRequest>
```

So I generate the same LogoutRequest with properties of Signature, but I have get same error (SessionIndex not present...).

My biggest doubts are related to Destination, NameID Format, and SPNameQualifier.

What is the correct value of the Destination? I have seen elsewhere that I should insert the Destination with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/saml2`, I saw also `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-azure-id>/saml2`.

So, do I still have to send my POST request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf` even though my Destination app is one of the above commented out? or should I send the POST to the same local location as Destination?

The NameID Format is placing the same as the SAMLResponse uploaded (which I sent to Office 365).

The SPNameQualifier is already using the same value set in Issuer (ImmutableID).

Example of the data I send in my post:

```
SAMLRequest=nVLdSsMwFH6Vkvt0TWs3F9bCYAiFKerEC29GSE9roE1qTirz2bzwkXwF025DHajgTchJvvP9nGSBom3ijq9NbXp3C089oAtWflFaOGV0Rh6d65BPJo2plQ5bJa1BUzmjG6UhlKY93KCtSFCsMrKNp0nCWCmphEjQmMmEzqMyoTGwhMWyBBafeShiD4VGJ7TLSByxlEaMsuSOJTxlPJ2F89n5AwnuweJoJA4jEuzaRiPfu85IbzU3AhVyLVpA7iTfLC/X3EN5Z40z0jQkX4xwPgrarwy/EwhEsMMMSP7++nYcg9+2LxS0A9tZhUCl0ZWqezuOiz6LpofF5KviUf/KKxSr4MLYVrifpVnIxhNV0mqEcmiFapZlaQGRBJvrgeimF42qFNjPB/rTFvlXdk/7nWtAU+9OaWqSaXoMu4+XB2Pajm+8WY8udAm7fIv7yvf4ktagwZPBQDGgqU/WGY2HwZ00BweFk1+afwA=
SigAlg=http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
RelayState=data_sended_for_microsoft_in_login_value
Signature=UrlEncoded(Base64Encoded(SAMLRequest))&UrlEncoded(Base64Encoded(SigAlg))
```

I am also trying to find the location to configure Sign Out in my application in Administrative Tools, but haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

1. The correct value of the Destination attribute is always the URL you are sending the SAML request to (or, rather, instruct the user’s browser to send (in this case, POST) the request to).
2. When using the POST binding, you should not use separate `SigAlg` and `Signature` attributes, you should include the signature as a XML signature in the SAML2 XML message itself. These two attributes are used only in the HTTP-Redirect binding.